# How to stop task and mouse cursor when having exception

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

Im using the following code and the problem is that when I have exception in GetUserData()
I get message to the UI and the mouse courser is not stopping ,when I put inside the catch
the mouse Cursors.Null cause to dump.
my questions is:

> 1. How I can stop the task (tpl) when I got exception i.e. not proceed to the continueWith ?
> 2. How can I omit the mouse cursor when I got exception ?

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() =>
    {
        //-----get service Data ---------
        try
        {
            GetUsersData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _isValid = false;
            ThrowErrorMessage(e.Message);
             Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Null;
        }
    })
    .ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    isServiceValid = true;
```

Comment: Why use `ContinueWith` rather than `async/await`, are you limited to VS2010? Otherwise, if you need to target .NET 4.0 but develop with VS2012+ , you still can use `async/await`, Microsoft provides the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) library for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exeptions with `Task.Wait()`. If there was a exeption due the execution it will be re thrown there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This article describes that behavior very good.

To the 2end problem: If you want to change the Cursor ourside of the Dispatcher thread you need to reinvoke your action back to the Dispatcher with:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Null));
```